# Accessing variables from a .m file

Tags: matlab

I run a program, which is a function - here I'll call it 'myfxn' - that outputs several different variables. But when I try to access the data I get

```
??? Undefined function or variable 'myfxn'.
```

How do I access the data? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is myfxn the name of the function or the variable? Keep in mind that function variables are local to the function. You can't see them in the workspace. Also check that you are in the same directory of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit confusing - you claim you run the function, but then you also say that Matlab throws an error indicating it can't run the function.

Here's two things to test

1. Is `myfxn` on the Matlab path? Run the command `which myfxn`. If that does not find the function, change directory (using `cd` or the directory browser on the Matlab Desktop) to where `myfxn` is located.
2. Does the function actually generate output? If it's a function, the first line should look something like this: `function [out1,out2] = myfxn(in1,in2)`, where `in1` and `in2` are two input arguments, and `out1` and `out2` are output arguments. Then, you could call `myfxn` like this: `[a,b] = myfxn(2,'something');`, and it will use the two inputs to generate the two outputs, which are assigned to `a`, and `b`, respectively.